# MBProgressHUD fades before finishing load

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

The MBProgressHUD fades before fully loading on app that loads a large database.

I have searched for answers to this but I cannot work out what I need to do to fix this.

This is my current code

```
-(void)beginParsing {
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = LOCALIZED(@"LOADING");
hud.detailsLabelText = LOCALIZED(@"LOADING2");
[self.view addSubview:hud];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    _dictJSON = [self performParsing];
} completionBlock:^{
    [hud removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setData:_dictJSON];
    [self getCategories];
    [self setFeaturedRestaurants];
    [listView reloadData];
}];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `fully loading`?

Comment: must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. *Questions which are too broad, unclear, and incomplete

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @JonathanGagne Your comment isn't exactly clear either?!

Comment: It is a copy/past of the actual convention to follow for asking question. If you have a question please ask.

Comment: don't worry about it, I'll work it out myself, I didn't realise this forum was full of assholes